# Batch programming code explanation needed

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to understand a batch script I found online , the code is designed to check for the last day of the month and terminate the script if the condition is true.

Heres a copy of the code.

```
REM @echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') do set day=%%a & set month=%%b & set year=%%c

set /a leap=%year% %% 3
if %leap%==0 (set eom=29) else (set eom=28)

echo 01 03 05 07 08 10 12 | find "%month%" > nul && set eom=31
echo 04 06 09 11 | find "%month%" > nul && set eom=30

rem if %eom%==%day% exit
```

however I understand the rest of the code all except the following two lines.

```
set /a leap=%year% %% 3
if %leap%==0 (set eom=29) else (set eom=28)
```

when I've tried to Echo the contents of the leap variable I keep getting 2, but if I'm honest don't truly understand how it would ever get 0 ?

any advice on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%%` means modulus, since each leap year is 4 years apart e.g. 2012(leap),2013,2014,2015,2016(2nd leap), if value of a leap year is 0, then value of the last year before another leap year is 4.( Think of an array, [0,1,2,3,5], 0 to 4 is 5 numbers apart). And so, 2016 is another leap year, since its value 4 is the 5th number from 0. 
If you still confused why modulo 4? Because the leap year divided by 4 is 0, so as I said before, 0 means a leap year.

Comment: `Modulo 3` will give eihter `0`, `1` or `2` - resulting in every third year calculated as a leap year.  It has to be `%% 4` to calculate leap years correct (at least in a short timeframe. See @dohaqatar's answer for the exact calculation rules)

Comment: @Stephan Oh ya its 4, i confused myself when I wrote 2013(leap) instead of 2012(leap)

Comment: @Stephan, thank you very much for the modulus answer, the moment I tried 2015 mod 4 in my calculator and then 2016 mod 4 it all became clear!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like The `%leap%` variable is being used to check if a year is a leap year. You only ever get 2 when you `echo %leap%` because `2015 % 3` will always be 2.

It also seems that the logic for checking if it's a leap year is flawed. A general approach for this is

> 1. If the year is evenly divisible by 4, go to step 2. Otherwise, go to step 5.
> 2. If the year is evenly divisible by 100, go to step 3. Otherwise, go to step 4.
> 3. If the year is evenly divisible by 400, go to step 4. Otherwise, go to step 5.
> 4. The year is a leap year (it has 366 days).
> 5. The year is not a leap year (it has 365 days).

[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214019)